# Do spambots fill out forms with only a file field?

Tags: forms, spam

I have a public form that *only* has a file field. Do spambots fill this kind of forms too? Will I need a captcha? Thanks.

Comment: Any kind of files, its kind of an upload website.

Comment: If you allow them to upload arbitrary content which you then serve up so they can link to it, then yes, they will come in droves. Stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow unrestricted access, yes. You need to show a captcha, and hopefully allow users to register (registration should also be enforced by captcha).

Comment: Because bots will submit spam files, I presume?

Comment: @FelipeSchenone: Because someone may build a bot just to spam your specific websites. Don't ever say "it won't happen to me" because it happens to everyone. :)